# How to make name of users uniques by adding number of occurrence?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce, for-of-loop

I've list of users:

```js
const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Leanne Graham",
    phone: "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Ervin Howell",
    phone: "010-692-6593 x09125",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Leanne Graham",
    phone: "1-463-123-4447",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Leanne Graham",
    phone: "493-170-9623 x156",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Chelsey Dietrich",
    phone: "(254)954-1289",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Mrs. Dennis Schulist",
    phone: "1-477-935-8478 x6430",
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "Kurtis Weissnat",
    phone: "210.067.6132",
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V",
    phone: "586.493.6943 x140",
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: "Glenna Reichert",
    phone: "(775)976-6794 x41206",
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "Leanne Graham",
    phone: "024-648-3804",
  },
];
for (const user of users) {
  let countUserOccured = users.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => (acc += curr.name == user.name),
    0
  );
  if (countUserOccured - 1 != 0) {
    user.name += countUserOccured;
  }
  console.log(user);
}
```

And I want users name be unique.
if the name e.g. "Leanne Graham" in that case repeated many times I want first one add to his name 1, second one his name 2...
I've tried this approach: *but its order DESC(from greater number of occurrence to the lowest I want it in order ASCending.*

```js
for (const user of users) {
  let countUserOccured = users.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => (acc += curr.name == user.name),
    0
  );
  if (countUserOccured - 1 != 0) {
    user.name += countUserOccured;
  }
  console.log(user);
}
```

Comment: You only need 1 reduce.

Comment: what do you want, if the user does not repeat?

Comment: This shouldn't be solved on the front-end though. It is a problem is the database or whatever, where the users are stored.

Comment: @NinaScholz just to not repeat the same name again and again..

Comment: You can't have a desc/asc order of object properties based on value because object properties are not ordered.

Comment: @TheFool Yeah it's a bad design of DataBase, But for sure there's a solution, I've tried this but I would like to know more approaches to solve this problem!

Comment: @Andy Yes they are not in a specific order, but the problem is to show number occurrence (which will make name unique) in ASC not DESC like I did!

Comment: Can you add an example of the output you want to your question because it's very unclear.

Comment: Why do you want to mess with the names? Your entries already have a unique ID.

Comment: I found this question because my github copilot is using this information to autocomplete fields. Crazy stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with objects and counting the value that you want.

```
const counts = {};
users.forEach((user) => {
  counts[user.name] = (counts[user.name] || 0) + 1;
});
console.log(counts)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could map new objects with incremented name count. The first same name does not get a number.

```js
const
    users = [{ id: 1, name: "Leanne Graham", phone: "1-770-736-8031 x56442" }, { id: 2, name: "Ervin Howell", phone: "010-692-6593 x09125" }, { id: 3, name: "Leanne Graham", phone: "1-463-123-4447" }, { id: 4, name: "Leanne Graham", phone: "493-170-9623 x156" }, { id: 5, name: "Chelsey Dietrich", phone: "(254)954-1289" }, { id: 6, name: "Mrs. Dennis Schulist", phone: "1-477-935-8478 x6430" }, { id: 7, name: "Kurtis Weissnat", phone: "210.067.6132" }, { id: 8, name: "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V", phone: "586.493.6943 x140" }, { id: 9, name: "Glenna Reichert", phone: "(775)976-6794 x41206" }, { id: 10, name: "Leanne Graham", phone: "024-648-3804" }],
    counts = {},
    result = users.map(o => ({ ...o, name: o.name + (counts[o.name] ? ++counts[o.name] : (counts[o.name] = 1, '')) }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi @Nina Scholz, you are legit the queen of data structures and I admire your skills. Are there any websites or resources I can use on improving my skills with these kind of problems? My skills are lacking when it comes to combining higher order functions.

Comment: @HelpANoobOut, sorry, for data structure, i can not help. for all other, you could have a look to https://developer.mozilla.org

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is (I added underscore before index for clarity):

```js
const userNamesMap = {};

const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Leanne Graham",
    phone: "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Ervin Howell",
    phone: "010-692-6593 x09125",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Leanne Graham",
    phone: "1-463-123-4447",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Leanne Graham",
    phone: "493-170-9623 x156",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Chelsey Dietrich",
    phone: "(254)954-1289",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Mrs. Dennis Schulist",
    phone: "1-477-935-8478 x6430",
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "Kurtis Weissnat",
    phone: "210.067.6132",
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V",
    phone: "586.493.6943 x140",
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: "Glenna Reichert",
    phone: "(775)976-6794 x41206",
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "Leanne Graham",
    phone: "024-648-3804",
  },
].map(user => {
  if (userNamesMap[user.name]) {
    user.name += `_${userNamesMap[user.name]++}`
  } else {
    userNamesMap[user.name] = 1;
  }
  return user;
});

console.log(users);
```

Comment: Please do not use `.map()` for simple array iteration. Use `.forEach()` or a normal loop to do that.

Answer (score 1):

As so often, I am much slower than @Nina :D but here is my two cents worth of code:

```js
const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Leanne Graham",
    phone: "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Ervin Howell",
    phone: "010-692-6593 x09125",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Leanne Graham",
    phone: "1-463-123-4447",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Leanne Graham",
    phone: "493-170-9623 x156",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Chelsey Dietrich",
    phone: "(254)954-1289",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Mrs. Dennis Schulist",
    phone: "1-477-935-8478 x6430",
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "Kurtis Weissnat",
    phone: "210.067.6132",
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V",
    phone: "586.493.6943 x140",
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: "Glenna Reichert",
    phone: "(775)976-6794 x41206",
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "Leanne Graham",
    phone: "024-648-3804",
  },
];

const cnts={};
let output = users.map(u=> {
  if(cnts[u.name])
    u.name+= cnts[u.name]++;
  else cnts[u.name]=1;
  return u;
});

console.log(output);
```

I also use an object (`cnts`) to keep track of the number of occurrences. But in the `.map()` I resort to a good old fashioned `if/else` construct to rename the user (or not).